# How can I get the average (mean) of selected columns

Tags: r

I would like to get the average for certain columns for each row.

I have this data:

```
w=c(5,6,7,8)
x=c(1,2,3,4)
y=c(1,2,3)
length(y)=4
z=data.frame(w,x,y)
```

Which returns:

```
  w x  y
1 5 1  1
2 6 2  2
3 7 3  3
4 8 4 NA
```

I would like to get the mean for certain columns, not all of them.  My problem is that there are a lot of NAs in my data.  So if I wanted the mean of x and y, this is what I would like to get back:

```
  w x  y mean
1 5 1  1    1
2 6 2  2    2
3 7 3  3    3
4 8 4 NA    4
```

I guess I could do something like `z$mean=(z$x+z$y)/2` but the last row for y is NA so obviously I do not want the NA to be calculated and I should not be dividing by two.  I tried `cumsum` but that returns NAs when there is a single NA in that row.  I guess I am looking for something that will add the selected columns, ignore the NAs, get the number of selected columns that do not have NAs and divide by that number.  I tried ??mean and ??average and am completely stumped.

ETA: Is there also a way I can add a weight to a specific column?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here are some examples:

```
> z$mean <- rowMeans(subset(z, select = c(x, y)), na.rm = TRUE)
> z
  w x  y mean
1 5 1  1    1
2 6 2  2    2
3 7 3  3    3
4 8 4 NA    4
```

*weighted mean*

```
> z$y <- rev(z$y)
> z
  w x  y mean
1 5 1 NA    1
2 6 2  3    2
3 7 3  2    3
4 8 4  1    4
> 
> weight <- c(1, 2) # x * 1/3 + y * 2/3
> z$wmean <- apply(subset(z, select = c(x, y)), 1, function(d) weighted.mean(d, weight, na.rm = TRUE))
> z
  w x  y mean    wmean
1 5 1 NA    1 1.000000
2 6 2  3    2 2.666667
3 7 3  2    3 2.333333
4 8 4  1    4 2.000000
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I am looking for.  I really need to study up on this magical apply command, it seems like it is a solution to everything.

Answer (score 28):

Try using `rowMeans`:

```
z$mean=rowMeans(z[,c("x", "y")], na.rm=TRUE)

  w x  y mean
1 5 1  1    1
2 6 2  2    2
3 7 3  3    3
4 8 4 NA    4
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I normally use Extract, cannot believe I did not think of this.  Gave the check to kohske for including solution to weighted also.

Comment: @andrew How can I get rowMeans of a range of column with some particular name (e.g. MGW.1, MGW.2, MGW.3 ... MGW.198) so all of these columns have name starting with MGW but then number is different and I am not sure about exact number of such columns they could be 196 in one case and 198 in other. What I want is something like:  `data.frame(ID=DF[,1:4], MGW=rowMeans(DF[,MGW.*]), HEL=rowMeans(DF[,HEL.*]))` It means the first 4 columns should not be touched while for rest of the columns take average of all columns in category MGW.* and HEL.*

Comment: For that, I'd recommend using dplyr and tidyr, since dplyr lets you select columns based on regular expressions. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401788/dplyr-using-mutate-like-rowmeans) for an example, or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andrewheiss/dcd38268c65396e1f18de626e70cae47) for a worked example of this question.

Comment: @Andrew Hi, I am going to find the mean of every 10 columns of my data (which has 1000 columns) how should I modify it?Can you please guide me?Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a *tidyverse* solution using *c_across* which is designed for row-wise aggregations. This makes it easy to refer to columns by name, type or position *and* to apply any function to the selected columns.

```r
library("tidyverse")

w <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(1, 2, 3, NA)
z <- data.frame(w, x, y)

z %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    mean = mean(c_across(c(x, y)), na.rm = TRUE),
    max = max(c_across(x:y), na.rm = TRUE)
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       w     x     y  mean   max
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     5     1     1     1     1
#> 2     6     2     2     2     2
#> 3     7     3     3     3     3
#> 4     8     4    NA     4     4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>