# dplyr - using mutate() like rowmeans()

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't find the answer anywhere.

I would like to calculate new variable of data frame which is based on mean of rows.

For example:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(101,102,103), a=c(1,2,3), b=c(2,2,2), c=c(3,3,3))
```

I want to use mutate to make variable d which is mean of a,b and c. And I would like to be able to make that by selecting columns in way d=mean(a,b,c), and also I need to use range of variables (like in dplyr) d=mean(a:c).

And of course

```
mutate(data, c=mean(a,b))
```

or

```
mutate(data, c=rowMeans(a,b))
```

doesn't work.

Can you give me some tip?

Regards

Comment: `rowMeans` is for a matrix, not a vector of args. I'd suggest `data %>% mutate(c = Reduce("+",.)/length(.))`

Comment: Thanks - it works, but how to select only specific rows (for ex. p1 to p32)? And how to deal with NAs?

Comment: Could you modify your question to illustrate what you mean?

Answer (score 48):

You're looking for

```
data %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(c=mean(c(a,b)))

#      id     a     b     c
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1   101     1     2   1.5
# 2   102     2     2   2.0
# 3   103     3     2   2.5
```

or

```
library(purrr)
data %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(c=lift_vd(mean)(a,b))
```

Comment: Ah. Not bad at all. Unfortunately the documentation of `rowwise` is terrible (“`rowwise` does something under some situations. Here’s an undescriptive example for a single special case that cannot be generalised.”) so I end  up never using it. :-(

Comment: Another downside of `rowwise` is that you have to `ungroup` afterwards. A more appropriate name for the function might be `group_row` or something that makes the grouping explicit.

Answer (score 20):

dplyr is badly suited to operate on this kind of data because it assumes [tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) format and — for the problem in question — your data is untidy.

You can of course tidy it first:

```
tidy_data = tidyr::gather(data, name, value, -id)
```

Which looks like this:

```
   id name value
1 101    a     1
2 102    a     2
3 103    a     3
4 101    b     2
5 102    b     2
6 103    b     2
    …
```

And then:

```
tidy_data %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(mean = mean(value))
```

```
    name  mean
  (fctr) (dbl)
1      a     2
2      b     2
3      c     3
```

Of course this discards the original data. You could use `mutate` instead of `summarize` to avoid this. Finally, you can then un-tidy your data again:

```
tidy_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(mean = mean(value)) %>%
    tidyr::spread(name, value)
```

```
     id     mean     a     b     c
  (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1   101 2.000000     1     2     3
2   102 2.333333     2     2     3
3   103 2.666667     3     2     3
```

Alternatively, you could summarise and then merge the result with the original table:

```
tidy_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(value)) %>%
    inner_join(data, by = 'id')
```

The result is the same in either case. I conceptually prefer the second variant.

Comment: Incidentally: reshaping the data can be inefficient for very big tables but I use equivalent code with a data.frame that has several million rows, and it still works fine.

Comment: I forgot about that for dplyr data should be tidy - but in fact, for my purposes that kind of transformation seems to be very oblique way... But now i get it! :)

Comment: It would seem to me that OP's issue has more to do with `mean.default`'s awkward signature (dots after defaults) interacting with **dplyr**'s argument mapping than **dplyr**'s inability to work with 'untidy' data.

Answer (score 12):

And yet another couple of ways, useful if you have the numeric positions or vector names of the columns to be summarised:

```
data %>% mutate(d = rowMeans(.[, 2:4]))
```

or

```
data %>% mutate(d = rowMeans(.[, c("a","b","c")]))
```

Comment: pretty similar to my answer, but I like how you don't need to use `data.frame()` that kind of always bothered me. thanks.

Comment: this is the best solution, but made simpler by using select on the piped-in data frame. Have added an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I think the answer suggesting using `data.frame` or slicing on `.` is the best, but could be made simpler and more dplyr-ish like so:

```
data %>% mutate(c = rowMeans(select(., a,b)))
```

Or if you want to avoid `.`, with the penalty of having two inputs to your pipeline:

```
data %>% mutate(c = rowMeans(select(data, a,b)))
```

Comment: Yes. Use of `select` does increase the flexibility for choosing variables to be summed.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the dplyr-ish way. First, I'd create a function:

```
my_rowmeans = function(...) Reduce(`+`, list(...))/length(list(...))
```

Then, it can be used inside mutate:

```
data %>% mutate(rms = my_rowmeans(a, b))

#    id a b c rms
# 1 101 1 2 3 1.5
# 2 102 2 2 3 2.0
# 3 103 3 2 3 2.5

# or

data %>% mutate(rms = my_rowmeans(a, b, c))

#    id a b c      rms
# 1 101 1 2 3 2.000000
# 2 102 2 2 3 2.333333
# 3 103 3 2 3 2.666667
```

---

To deal with the possibility of `NAs`, the function must be uglified:

```
my_rowmeans = function(..., na.rm=TRUE){
  x = 
    if (na.rm) lapply(list(...), function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), as(0, class(x)))) 
    else       list(...)

  d = Reduce(function(x,y) x+!is.na(y), list(...), init=0)

  Reduce(`+`, x)/d
} 

# alternately...

my_rowmeans2 = function(..., na.rm=TRUE) rowMeans(cbind(...), na.rm=na.rm)

# new example

data$b[2] <- NA  
data %>% mutate(rms = my_rowmeans(a,b,na.rm=FALSE))

   id a  b c rms
1 101 1  2 3 1.5
2 102 2 NA 3  NA
3 103 3  2 3 2.5

data %>% mutate(rms = my_rowmeans(a,b))

   id a  b c rms
1 101 1  2 3 1.5
2 102 2 NA 3 2.0
3 103 3  2 3 2.5
```

The downside to the `my_rowmeans2` is that it coerces to a matrix. I'm not certain that this will always be slower than the `Reduce` approach, though.

Comment: my_rowmeans = function(...) Reduce(`+`, list(...))/length(list(...)) this is the very close solution of my problem. But how to deal with NAs? na.rm parameter would be very useful ;-)

Comment: @TomaszWojtas Updated. It would be better if your initial post reflected this as well (rather than extending the question in comments).

Answer (score 5):

Another simple possibility with few code is:

```
data %>%
    mutate(c= rowMeans(data.frame(a,b)))

 #     id a b   c
 #  1 101 1 2 1.5
 #  2 102 2 2 2.0
 #  3 103 3 2 2.5
```

As rowMeans needs something like a matrix or a data.frame, you can use `data.frame(var1, var2, ...)` instead of `c(var1, var2, ...)`. If you have NAs in your data you'll need to tell R what to do, for example to remove them: `rowMeans(data.frame(a,b), na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a `pivot_longer()`-style solution:

```
data%>%
pivot_longer(cols=-id)%>%
group_by(id)%>%
mutate(mean=mean(value))%>%
pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from=value)
```

Note that this requires the `tidyr` package.

This is my preference for the fact that I only need to type the name of my ID column, and don't have to worry about column indices or names otherwise.  Good for a quick copy-and-point-this-at-different-data solution, though the same can be said of other answers here. Also good for cases where you might have more than one column with categorical information and haven't created a single unique identifier column.

For what it's worth, I found that this solution is very easily modified to ignore NA values with simple addition of `na.rm=TRUE` in the mean calculation.

For example:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(101,102,103), a=c(NA,2,3), b=c(2,2,2), c=c(3,3,3))


data%>%
pivot_longer(cols=-id)%>%
group_by(id)%>%
mutate(mean=mean(value,na.rm=TRUE))%>%
pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from=value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper function around `rowMeans()` to make it easier to work with. The one below lets you specify `na.rm`, and you can use tidyselect to choose your columns if you want.

```r
# This is the wrapper function
means <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) {
  rowMeans(data.frame(...), na.rm = na.rm)
}

library(dplyr)

# Example data
iris2 <- iris %>% 
  head() %>% 
  transmute(Sepal.Length = replace(Sepal.Length,
                                   sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(.),
                                          replace = TRUE),
                                   NA),
            Sepal.Width,
            Petal.Length,
            Petal.Width) %>%
  print()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2
#> 2           NA         3.0          1.4         0.2
#> 3           NA         3.2          1.3         0.2
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#> 5           NA         3.6          1.4         0.2
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4


# Basic usage
iris2 %>% 
  mutate(mean_sepal = means(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width mean_sepal
#> 1           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2         NA
#> 2           NA         3.0          1.4         0.2         NA
#> 3           NA         3.2          1.3         0.2         NA
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       3.85
#> 5           NA         3.6          1.4         0.2         NA
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       4.65


# If you want to exclude NAs
iris2 %>% 
  mutate(mean_sepal = means(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, na.rm = TRUE))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width mean_sepal
#> 1           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2       3.50
#> 2           NA         3.0          1.4         0.2       3.00
#> 3           NA         3.2          1.3         0.2       3.20
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       3.85
#> 5           NA         3.6          1.4         0.2       3.60
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       4.65


# You can also use select() and choose columns using tidyselect
iris2 %>% 
  mutate(mean_sepal = means(select(., contains("Sepal")), na.rm = TRUE))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width mean_sepal
#> 1           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2       3.50
#> 2           NA         3.0          1.4         0.2       3.00
#> 3           NA         3.2          1.3         0.2       3.20
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       3.85
#> 5           NA         3.6          1.4         0.2       3.60
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       4.65
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>