# R: Averaging columns and conditionally excluding NA data

Tags: r

I'm trying to average across columns, however, because some of the columns are missing data, the average ends of being NA as well. 
Is there a way to find the mean of a number of columns while excluding any NA data from the calculation?

The code I've used so far is:

```
### Calculate Bins ###
 {pulse<-transmute(pulse, Question, Type, Student,Bin1=(Rt1+ Rt2 + Rt3+ Rt4)/4 , Bin2= (Rt5+Rt6+Rt7+Rt8)/4 , Bin3= (Rt9+Rt10+Rt11)/3)
 }
```

However, I don't think this is the best way.My goal is to have three columns with the means of Rt1-Rt4, Rt5-Rt8 and Rt9-Rt11. i.e. something like this:

```
 Question  Type Student  Bin1  Bin2     Bin3
1        Q   SNR  789331  4.25  4.00 4.666667
2       Q2   SNR  789331  3.75  2.50 3.000000
3       Q8   SNR  789331  4.00  2.50 3.333333
4      Q10   SNR  789331  4.00  2.75 3.333333
5      Q12   SNR  789331  3.50  3.25 3.666667
```

Any help would be appreciated!

My data is attached below:

```
> dput(pulse)
structure(list(Question = c("Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12"), Type = c("SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS"), Student = c("789331", 
"789331", "789331", "789331", "789331", "805933", "805933", "805933", 
"805933", "805933", "826523", "826523", "826523", "826523", "826523", 
"832929", "832929", "832929", "832929", "832929", "838607", "838607", 
"838607", "838607", "838607", "841903", "841903", "841903", "841903", 
"841903", "843618", "843618", "843618", "843618", "843618", "852125", 
"852125", "852125", "852125", "852125", "876406", "876406", "876406", 
"876406", "876406", "879972", "879972", "879972", "879972", "879972", 
"885650", "885650", "885650", "885650", "885650", "888712", "888712", 
"888712", "888712", "888712", "903303", "903303", "903303", "903303", 
"903303", "796882", "796882", "796882", "796882", "796882", "827911", 
"827911", "827911", "827911", "827911", "830271", "830271", "830271", 
"830271", "830271", "831487", "831487", "831487", "831487", "831487", 
"834598", "834598", "834598", "834598", "834598", "836364", "836364", 
"836364", "836364", "836364", "839802", "839802", "839802", "839802", 
"839802", "855524", "855524", "855524", "855524", "855524", "873527", 
"873527", "873527", "873527", "873527", "885409", "885409", "885409", 
"885409", "885409", "894218", "894218", "894218", "894218", "894218", 
"928026", "928026", "928026", "928026", "928026", "932196", "932196", 
"932196", "932196", "932196", "955389", "955389", "955389", "955389", 
"955389", "956952", "956952", "956952", "956952", "956952", "957206", 
"957206", "957206", "957206", "957206", "957759", "957759", "957759", 
"957759", "957759", "959200", "959200", "959200", "959200", "959200", 
"962490", "962490", "962490", "962490", "962490", "968728", "968728", 
"968728", "968728", "968728", "969005", "969005", "969005", "969005", 
"969005", "971179", "971179", "971179", "971179", "971179", "976863", 
"976863", "976863", "976863", "976863", "981621", "981621", "981621", 
"981621", "981621", "952797", "952797", "952797", "952797", "952797", 
"965873", "965873", "965873", "965873", "965873", "967416", "967416", 
"967416", "967416", "967416", "975424", "975424", "975424", "975424", 
"975424"), Rt1 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 
4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt2 = c(4, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 
3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 
2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Rt3 = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 4, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 4), Rt4 = c(5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
5, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 
3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt5 = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 
3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 
4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
3, 3, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt6 = c(4, 
2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
5, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
4, 4, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 
5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt7 = c(5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 
2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 
2, 3, 4), Rt8 = c(4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 
5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt9 = c(4, 
3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt10 = c(5, 3, 3, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
1, 1, 1, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 4, 
3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 
3, 1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 4), Rt11 = c(5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 
4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Question", "Type", 
"Student", "Rt1", "Rt2", "Rt3", "Rt4", "Rt5", "Rt6", "Rt7", "Rt8", 
"Rt9", "Rt10", "Rt11"), row.names = c(NA, -205L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please add the names of any packages you are using. `transmute` is not a base R function.

Comment: See `?mean`. You need `na.rm=T`
For the colum Rt1 in your example: `mean(pulse$Rt1, na.rm=T)`

Comment: @SRivero
Thanks! That helps, but I'm trying to average across columns (i.e. I want the mean of Rt1, RT2 and Rt3) for each student. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, `rowMeans`

Comment: `Bin1 = rowMeans(pulse[,4:7], na.rm = TRUE); Bin2 = rowMeans(pulse[,8:11], na.rm = TRUE); Bin3 = rowMeans(pulse[,12:14], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

To generate mean of rows:

```
dataframe <- pulse[(number_of_rows_you_are_interested_in),]   
rowMeans(dataframe, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to apply this so that it averages columns Rt1-Rt4, Rt5-Rt8 and Rt9-Rt11 to create three new mean columns? 
I'm a complete R beginner, so additional explanation might be needed and would definitely be appreciated! :)

Comment: @Bailey If you want to average rows from different columns and save result in new column use `mutate` from `dplyr` package. `pulse %>% mutate(new_column1 = mean(c(Rt1:Rt4)), new_column2 = mean(c(Rt5:Rt8)), new_column3 = mean(c(Rt9:Rt11)))` use column numbers instead of column names.

Comment: you don't even need dplyr. follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490485/how-can-i-get-the-average-mean-of-selected-columns

Answer (score 0):

```
Rt1[!is.na(Rt1)]
```

The above code returns the reduced dataframe by excluding all NA entries in Rt1

You may use this expression across your columns

Answer (score 0):

I've found `complete.cases()` to be particularly useful to only give you rows that have no NAs

```
pulse <- pulse[complete.cases(pulse), ]
```

and then you should be able to calculate over this dataframe

also, instead of having to manually calculate the average, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490485/how-can-i-get-the-average-mean-of-selected-columns)'s example (which is pretty similar to your question to begin with)